# TLS 1.2 finished message stucture

Tags: tls

I am implementing TLS 1.2 and using **ECDHE_RSA_AES_128_GCM_SHA256** cipher suit.

According to RFC 5246 finished messages have {verify_data[verify_data_length]} and **verify_data = PRF(master_secret, finished_label, hash(handshake_messages)**

Some people said client finished contain **Authentication tag** and **nonce** along whit **verify data**. Can anyone tell me the structure of finished message in this cipher suit and exactly the size of verify data, authentication tag and nonce.

Below is my Client Finished message @Makif can you tell me how may bytes are encrypted and where is authentication tag in this message?

[image]

@Makif, Got it.

-8 byte nonce

-16 byte ciphertext

-16 byte authentication tag

Total is 40 byte but my finished message contain 48 bytes. What is about last 8 byte?

Comment: Same as http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/34754/what-does-the-tls-1-2-client-finished-message-contain except this time you put all of the question in the question, making @Makif's answer clearer.