# DTLS 1.2 Finished message

Tags: tls, transport-security

I am implementing **DTLS 1.2** and using **ECDHE_RSA_AES_128_GCM_SHA256** cipher suit.

Below is my client finished message

[image]

Can anyone explain this message?

How many bytes for verify data?

Is there authentication tag if yes then how many bytes for authentication tag?

And how many bytes for nonce?

And is all the message encrypted if not then how many bytes are encrypted?

How can i verify this message?

Comment: You should stop asking the same question from different threads. If necessary edit [this question](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/35024/tls-1-2-finished-message-stucture)

Comment: @Makif i edited but no one answer it yet. If you know the answer kindly post it.

Comment: @Makif, since this is DTLS rather than TLS, perhaps you'd like to answer this separately?

Comment: @otus i dont know much about DTLS, i answered the [first question](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/35024/tls-1-2-finished-message-stucture) because i thought that it was about TLS. My objection is that those are the same questions, although the first one asks for "TLS 1.2 finished message" in the subject of the question, question itself asks for DTLS finished message.

Comment: @Makif, yeah, since your answer is about TLS, I think it makes sense to have these separate.

Comment: (@otus) Since the answer is *mostly* the same for DTLS vs TLS, plus in reviewing I found two minor mistakes, I have proposed an edit to http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/35024/tls-1-2-finished-message-stucture/35033#35033 to cover both. I expect(?) that will notify Makif and Ahsan.